# In DBSCAN, what happens if points have distance exactly equal to the Epsilon radius of a core point?

Tags: clustering, distance, dbscan

In DBSCAN the border points are points in the eps-neighborhood of a core point. But what if a point has distance exactly equal to Epsilon from a core point? Is it considered inside the eps radius, or not? Is it in the neighborhood of that core point, or not?

To be clearer, if distance = eps, is the point a border of that core point or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is at the border; how it is handled in practice might depend on the implementation, but formally speaking it *should* be included. In the original paper by [Ester et al. (1996)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/3001460.3001507), the Eps-neighbourhood of a point $p$ is defined using $\leq \text{Eps}$. Do note that in the unlikely event that a query point $q$ is *exactly* at the same distance between points $p_A$ and $p_B$ the order of processing the points will matter on whether $q$ is in the neighbourhood of $p_A$ or $p_B$.